# Using existing MySQL connection in PyCharm in python project without connecting manually again

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

I created a connection to a remote, tunneled MySQL server over the PyCharm GUI in the "Database" menu.

I'm trying to use this connection in the code itself, without connecting manually again to the SQL server and tunelling over SSH in the code.
Is this possible? I couldn't find anything relevant on the internet yet.

Thanks!